# Why does the Halacha distinguish between blessing for fragrance and before eating fruits

Tags: halacha-theory

The Halacha distinguishes between three types of blessing of the fragrance according to their source: בורא מיני בשמים, בורא עצי בשמים, בורא עשבי בשמים. However, when coming to eating fruits the Halacha distinguishes only between shrubs and trees: בורא פרי העץ, בורא פרי האדמה.
Why doesn't the Halacha make the same distinguish for blessing before eating?

Comment: עצי = העץ, עשבי =האדמה, מיני  = שהכל - I think would be a rough comparison.

Comment: Did you mean to ask why there is עצי and עשבי and הנותן ריח טוב בפירות?

Comment: @DoubleAA, this is an additional type of blessing and I can add it to the my question. The question is about different approach of the Halacha to blessing before eating to blessing before smelling.

Comment: The three you listed don't seem any different from foods though, so I don't get what you are asking about

Comment: The criteria for blessing before eating is if it grew from earth is if grew on shrub or tree. Whereas for smell the Halacha distinguishes between: fruit, tree, shrubs and other types of Besamim. I asked why is there difference? Is there a difference between taste and smell?

Comment: You just skipped food that didn't grow on plants. Not all smells grow on plants either. The only difference here is between tree fruits and tree non-fruits, which is why I asked above if you intended to ask about פירות

Comment: Not necessarily about fruits. I ask about different ways to categorize the the different objects (fruits, shurbs, trees, etc.) for different types of blessing for eating and smelling.